# Show msi installer UI from a managed WIX bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, wix3.9

I have an MSI installer and a managed C# bootstrapper. The purpose of the bootstrapper is to show a language select dialog and to launch the MSI with the appropriate language transform.
The bootstrapper relies on the MSI's UI:

```
 <Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Redist" />
  <RollbackBoundary />
  <MsiPackage Id="MyPackage" DisplayInternalUI="yes">
    <MsiProperty Name="TRANSFORMS" Value="[CommandArgs]"/>
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

Calling the following code shows the MSI's UI.

```
Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Install)
```

But uninstalling with the following uninstalls, the MSI witout showing any UI.

```
Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall)
Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Modify)
```

How can I make the bootstrapper show the MSI's UI for uninstall also?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking through the source it seems that Burn suppresses internal UI during uninstall and repair even if DisplayInternalUI is set. Not sure why your UI isn't showing during Modify.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this issue?